# Which is a good option to process multilingual data

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Hi i am using SQL SERVER 2012 and i need to do some analysis using multilingual data source. So which would be a better option using cubes or having separate columns for different languages? What are the pros and cons of Cubes

Answer (score 1):

Is this translations of column names or data?

If column names, you should have a read of using translations in SSAS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174552(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: It is translation of data not column name. i will get some records in different languages (French,Chinese etc)

Answer (score 1):

No the data translation should be handled in the Application Layer.

There are many service available and i would suggest Google API calls from Application

check this out

http://languagetranslator.codeplex.com/